# Integrate wordpress into index page

Tags: customization, directory

I have index page which is pure HTML/CSS `http://example.com/` and Wordpress blog into sub-folder `http://example.com/wp/`. What I want to do is to show most recent post + recent post widget from blog into specific div on index page which is not part of the wordpress.

Basically I want to show index page of this blog on main page..

Can you just guide me with some starting points how can be done this? Do I need some sort of iframe or how?

Comment: Use that index page as a custom page template in WordPress and instead of trying to load WordPress posts in that custom index page, use it in your WordPress theme and make it your WordPress front page. https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page